# Save single entity in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

Can I save a single entity in Symfony, without flushing all changes? E. g.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine();
$entity1 = $em->find('\SomeEntity', 1);
$entity2 = $em->find('\SomeEntity', 2);
$entity1->setFoo(1);
$entity1->persist();
$entity2->setFoo(2);
$this->saveRightNow($entity2); // entity2 is written to the DB at this point
$em->flush(); // entity1 is written to the DB at this point
```

Looking into the the source code, it seems I could use `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::commit`:

```
function saveRightNow($entity) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $uow->commit($entity);
}
```

but I couldn't find any documentation on using `commit` this way (nor much on using it at all, even though it is not marked as an internal function). Is this a good idea? Are there any dangers to it?

Comment: It's probably a terrible idea.  I can't say more than that without understanding what problem you're actually trying to solve.  I suspect you're missing something about what doctrine does for you, and are trying to work around a problem that either doesn't exist, or is anticipated by the library.

Comment: Basically I want entities which can save themselves, so that certain DB changes can be done deep inside model code, without the programmer of the controller having to care.

Comment: timdev, the reason of usage single entity commit is: 
1) to avoid launching of change tracking process witch is sometime costly; 
2) to separate some entity changes commit into the separate transaction; 
3) to control the order of commits to db

Answer (score 0):

All of our entities are subclasses of a superclass called Entity.php, which has a function like this:

```
public function save($flush = TRUE)
{
    try {
        self::getEntityManager()->persist($this);

        if ($flush) {
            self::getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

References to the getEntityManager can be supplied with your favourite way to get the EntityManager (we save ours into the Zend_Registry).

Comment: This does something completely different from what the question described. You cannot flush one saved change without flushing all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Also if this is an old question, maybe a reply may be useful to someone else as this is the first question that Google shows.

So, you cannot `flush` a single entity, but you can `detach` them.

So, in your particular case, you can do something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine();
$entity1 = $em->find('\SomeEntity', 1);
$entity2 = $em->find('\SomeEntity', 2);
$entity1->setFoo(1);
$entity2->setFoo(2);

// At this point start the "new" code
// So, first detach $entity2
$em->detach($entity2); // Now the EntityManager doesn't know anymore of $entity2
$em->flush(); // entity1 is written to the DB at this point

// Add again $entity2 to the EntityManager
$em->persist($entity2);
$em->flush();
```

Obviously, this is a really simple example.

In a real use case,, maybe you have loaded into the EntityManager more than 2 entities. In this case, also if you `detach($entity2)` may be that the EntityManager with the first `flush()` will save to the database also the modifications made to other loaded entities.

So, this solution have to be used with care.

Another solution may be the use of `clear()`: this detaches all the managed entities. It is really similar to a fresh EntityManager that is just initialized.

I've used this last solution recently to save only partial data of an entity that have some related entities that have to not be saved.

So, I:

1. First cleared the entity manager;
2. Then reloaded the entity I was updating;
3. Made the relevant modifications;
4. Flushed the EntityManager

It may be a little complex to made very specific flushes, and, sure, it would be really helpful to have a method to save only partially an entity.

But for the moment those approaches are the only ones possible.